# Collision detection issue or my logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, collision

I created a little prototype of movement using jQuery / HTML5 Canvas with a tile map algorithm. My problem is the collision is acting odd. I'll explain, if I move left and right the collision is detected and movement is halted, if I move up and down the same occurs. If I move left and right (collision occurs) THEN up and down collision is no longer true when I move up and down after I already collided left and right.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYWyh/5/)

Here is a snippet of my detection and movement

```
            if (keydown == UP) {
                if (!hasCollided(pX, pY - v, mX, mY)) pY -= v;
                keydown = null;
            } else if (keydown == DOWN) {
                if (!hasCollided(pX, pY + v, mX, mY)) pY += v;
                keydown = null;
            } else if (keydown == LEFT) {
                if (!hasCollided(pX - v, pY, mX, mY)) pX -= v;
                keydown = null;
            } else if (keydown == RIGHT) {
                if (!hasCollided(pX + v, pY, mX, mY)) pX += v;
                keydown = null;
            }
```

Any help with my logic would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code in `hasCollided()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt84k/) ya go! It isn't all that much different. Mostly you checked you moved the player every time you checked a tile for collision, so if at least one tile that was checked didn't collide the player moved anyway.

So that makes:

```
var desPosX = 0;
    var desPosY = 0;
    if (keydown == UP) {
        desPosY = -v;
    } else if (keydown == DOWN) {
        desPosY = v;
    }
    if (keydown == LEFT) {
        desPosX = -v;
    } else if (keydown == RIGHT) {
        desPosX = v;
    }
    var collided = false;
    if(!gliding)
        keydown = null;
    for (var y = minY; y < maxY; y++) {
        for (var x = minX; x < maxX; x++) {
            if (map[y][x] == 1) {
                mX = x * 32;
                mY = y * 32;
            }

            if (hasCollided(desPosX+pX, desPosY+pY, mX, mY)) {
                collided = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!collided) {
        pX += desPosX;
        pY += desPosY;
    }
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks that is more then what I was looking for. Much appreciated.